# Open JQuery Popup after Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with jquery mobile.

here is teh jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gc7mR/3/

First i have a Panel with some Buttons, The importan Button is the button with id=define)!

```
<div data-role=header data-position=fixed>
        <div data-role=navbar>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#define data-role=button data-icon=edit
                    data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" id="define"
                    data-position-to="#map_canvas">Define</a></li>
                <li><a href=#compose data-role=button data-icon=gear
                    data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown"
                    data-position-to="#map_canvas">Compose</a></li>
                <li><a href=#search data-role=button data-icon=search
                    data-inline="true" id="search">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now i created 3 Popups(one of them is shown below). Further i have a variable called scenario, which can change the states between restaurants,landmarks, and movies. My goal is  if the Button with the id 'define' is clicked, the corresponding popup to the actual state of teh scenario variable should be opened(e.g. if scenario="landmarks" the popup with the id landmarks should open).

```
<div data-role="popup" id="defineLandmarks"
        style="width: 600px; height: 750px;">
        <div style="padding: 20px;">
            <div align="center">
                <b>please define options for the landmark scenario</b>
            </div>

            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">wiki abstract</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px;; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="wiki_abstract" id="wiki_abstract" value=""
                            data-clear-btn="false"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">wiki text</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="wiki_text" id="wiki_text" value="" data-clear-btn="false">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">keywords 1</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="keywords1" id="keywords1" value="" data-clear-btn="false">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">keywords 2</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="keywords2" id="keywords2" value="" data-clear-btn="false">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">keywords 3</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="keywords3" id="keywords3" value="" data-clear-btn="false">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">keywords 4</td>
                        <td style="width: 450px; float: right"><input type="text"
                            name="keywords4" id="keywords4" value="" data-clear-btn="false">

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                </table>




                <form>
                    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"
                        align="center">
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="resetLandmarks">Reset</a> <a
                            href="#" data-role="button" id="applyLandmarks">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I try to open the poup like this but it does not work:

```
$("#define").click(function() {
    var s= getScenario();

    if(s=='restaurant'){
        $('#defineRestaurants').popup('open');
    }
    else if(s=='movies'){
        $('#defineMovies').popup('open');
    }
    else if(s=='landmarks'){
        $('#defineLandmarks').popup('open');
    }else{
        alert("Please choose a scenario");
    }


});
```

Comment: which is the `popup` plugin used

Comment: how is `defineMovies` defined

Comment: Create a fiddle for this at ***http://jsfiddle.net***, and we'll be better able to help you. Include all your supporting functions.

Comment: defineMovies and  defineRestaurants are popups like the sample in the middle of my post

Comment: i got it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gc7mR/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at something like

```
$(createToggleHandler("#check", "#most", "#most"));

function createToggleHandler(id, target, scroll){
    return function(){
        $(id).click(createToggleClickHandler(target, scroll));
    }
}
function createToggleClickHandler(target, scroll){
    return function(){
        var x = $(target);
        x.toggle(500);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll).offset().top }, 1000);
    }
}
```